# Aurelia select initial value

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have the following code:

javascript:

```
export class App {
  values = [
    {id: 0, text:'Text 1'},
    {id: 1, text:'Text 2'},
    {id: 2, text:'Text 3'}
  ];

  obj = {
    selected: 2
  };
}
```

html:

```
<template>
  <select value.bind="obj.selected">
    <option repeat.for="option of values" value="${option.id}">${option.text}</option>
  </select>
</template>
```

The problem is that the initial value of the `select` is not the thirth option as expected.

What I have to do to make it works correctly?

[**Plunk example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ddl87Fr6lvoz0dehMn8p?p=preview)

Comment: @blm - I don't think that my question is a duplicate of the one that you have linked...

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate of the linked answer. Completely different issues and questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `id` property is of type number so you'll want to make sure each option element's "value" is also of type number.  This means you do not want to use a string interpolation binding (eg `${...}`) because these always convert the source value to a string.  You also won't want to use the option element's `value` attribute to store the value because this attribute only accepts strings.  Instead use the `model` property which is a special property aurelia's binding system understands and can store any type.  These kinds of scenarios are discussed in the docs [here](https://aurelia.io/docs/binding/selects).

tldr: change your option element binding to this:

```html
<option repeat.for="option of values" model.bind="option.id">${option.text}</option>
```

Comment: The current Aurelia doc page for select is here: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-selects/1 :)

Comment: Here's a working link: https://aurelia.io/docs/binding/selects/